# Automatic Image Cropping JavaScript Tool Suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-processing, vue.js, marvin-framework

I wanted to see if anyone knew of a browser (or possibly even Java) tool where I can upload an image and it will make an effort to find different characters and crop them out to individual images.

For example, in this image, I'd like for the tool to find three unique runic symbols and save them out to individual files.  It's not really OCR because we aren't interpreting what the characters are, we just need to recognize that there's a bit of white space between them, so let's take that and save them.

[image]

My company has the "you're a programmer, so you should be able to do this, right?" attitude, and I need to provide solutions or alternatives to the requirement.  I know that there are many tools where the user can manually crop, but they are specifically looking for an automagic tool to reduce the amount of user activity.

If a (preferably Java) server side tool is available, I'd definitely be open to that as well.

Any jQuery, Vue, or even Java, etc. advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Imagemagick worked based on the response from @fmw42 below, but we found another tool called the Marvin Image Processing Framework that is doing what we need and it's native Java.

http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

Comment: Put it into canvas. Read teh pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ImageMagick, there is a connected-components tool that would do what you want with a little unix scripting. It only works if there is white separation between the characters. I believe that OpenCV also has something similar.

Input:

[image]

Lets start with just the connected-components to show the textual data returned:

```
convert rUNOP.png -alpha off -threshold 50% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | sed 's/^[ ]*//'

Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
0: 236x139+0+0 118.2,71.3 30849 gray(255)
2: 36x50+27+11 39.7,30.5 630 gray(0)
3: 29x50+90+11 103.3,34.3 580 gray(0)
1: 23x50+155+9 163.3,33.3 502 gray(0)
4: 13x24+160+21 165.0,32.9 243 gray(255)
```

Now combine that with some scripting to find those entries with black i.e., gray(0) color and extract the bounding box and use that to crop the input image.

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert rUNOP.png -alpha off -threshold 50% -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 4 null: | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`)
num=${#arr[*]}
IFS=$OLDIFS
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
bbox=`echo ${arr[$i]} | cut -d\  -f2`
color=`echo ${arr[$i]} | cut -d\  -f5`
if [ "$color" = "gray(0)" ]; then
convert rUNOP.png -crop $bbox +repage rUNOP_crop_$i.gif
fi
done
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's awesome!  Since I'm (unfortunately) forced to use Windows for this project, I think I'll take this and see if JMagick can do the same thing.  If not, some command line voodoo might work.

Thanks!

Comment: You could install Cygwin for unix on Windows or use Windows 10 built-in unix. Otherwise, you might be able to find a Windows expert that can convert my Unix commands into comparable commands for Windows. It is primarily just loading the text into an array and then doing a for loop to find the correct color and bounding box.

Comment: We are unfortunately forced to use Win 7 and Cygwin is not allowed for some crazy reason.  Based on your brilliant code, we should be able to convert that to Java if it comes to that.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There's no libraries that'll do the cropping for your that I know of. One way of solving this is to use imagemagick to crop the image, but you'll have to figure out where to crop.

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php

Good luck :)